# Python QRcode Alphanumeric

Tags: python, django, qr-code, alphanumeric

I'm looking for a pythonic (hopefully pure pythonic, since I'd like to embed QRcodes as Data-URI) library to handle Alphanumeric QR code generation.

Basically, the [pyqrnative](https://github.com/unapiedra/pyqrnative/blob/master/PyQRNative.py) library is great, but it handles only 8bitbyte QR codes - a massive waste of space for alphanumeric codes (2 chars in 11 bits). A lot of the libraries out there are forks of this - do you have any experience generating data-uri for an Alphanumeric QR code?